# Operator evaluation in Scala - one is endless loop, the other works

Tags: scala, loops

I recently started a Coursera specialization, and one of the assignments requires the implementation of the union operation for a binary tree set. I originally coded it as:

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = ((left union right) union that) incl elem
```

But in my tests, it resulted in an endless loop. Then, I tried:

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = (left union (right union that)) incl elem
```

And it worked as I expected! Now, I'm glad it worked, but I cannot figure out what causes the difference between the 2 implementations. Could you help me find it?

Comment: This is a great example of a problem where stepping through things with a  debugger would quickly reveal the issue.